# tastypie access request username under meta class

Tags: python, tastypie

I have a tastypie resource class as below

```
class ItemsResource(ModelResource):

    taxclass_id=fields.CharField(attribute='taxclass_id_id')
    parent_id=fields.CharField(attribute='parent_id_id')
    branch_id=fields.CharField(attribute='branch_id_id')
    isactive=fields.CharField(attribute='isactive_id')
    metric=fields.CharField(attribute='metric')
    class Meta:
        username=<<how to access request.username here!>>
        queryset = Item.objects.filter(username=username)
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
```

I want to filter queryset based on the request username, how do I access request.username inside Meta class

Answer (score 1):

I think the same filtering can be achieved by overriding get_object_list method

```
    def get_object_list(self, request):
        username=request.GET['username']
        return super(ItemsResource, self).get_object_list(request).filter(username=username)
```